# How to use Selenium to navigate through sports site for web scraping Soccer Player Prop data?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

I am new to coding and trying to learn how to navigate through a website using Selenium. My ultimate goal is to parse Soccer Player Prop Data [player props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDTFQ.png) in order to print the output to excel using a Pandas DataFrame.

In order to access this info, I believe I must first finish 4 steps (please correct me if I am wrong):

1) select tab "OVER/UNDER" on the player props page

2) scroll down to "UCL" (Champions League Soccer)

3) select the option "ALL Available (across all games)"

4) select the tab "Shots(Player)"

[image]

I found the "Over/Under" button using the Xpath:

## Updated code to change iframes and click Over/Under button

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from time import sleep


 class App:
     def __init__(self,):

         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
         self.main_url = 'https://www.betonline.ag/sportsbook/player-props'
         self.driver.get(self.main_url)
         sleep(3)

         self.driver.switch_to.frame("builder")
         element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a/b')
         element.click()

         sleep(3)
         self.driver.close()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = App()
```

I am now able to select the "Over/Under" tab. I will start working on steps 2-4 next.

The Soccer Prop data I am looking for is "Player", "Over", "Line", and "Under".

Here is a sample of the excel output I am looking for:

```
  Player               Over         Line          Under

Divock Origi          -108          3.5          -120
```

I was hoping to create a loop so I can parse all of the player's bet info.

I can see the Over/Under button in the code but not sure how to parse correctly:

[image]

I can also see the player data:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this project? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will continue to work on this and will update my code if make any additional progress. Thank you so much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which displayed data in `dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.betonline.ag/sportsbook/player-props")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"builder")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='one-third one-third-remove']//a[./b[contains(.,'Over / Under')]]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-if='selected.league']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@ng-repeat='league in leagues']/a[.//span[text()='UCL']]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-if^='selected.game']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li/a[.//div[text()='All Available']]"))).click()
#WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(.,'Shots (Player)')]"))).click()


player=[]
Over=[]
line=[]
Under=[]
Playersname=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='div-table__row__cell hard--bottom hard--right ng-scope']//a[@class='ng-binding']")))
for players in Playersname:
    player.append(players.text)

OverAndUnder=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a>b.milli.caps.ng-binding")))
count=int(len(OverAndUnder)/2)
x=0
for i in range(count):
    Over.append(OverAndUnder[x].text)
    Under.append(OverAndUnder[x+1].text)
    x=x+2

lines=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-class*='overUnder']>b")))
for l in lines:
    line.append(l.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Player":player,"Over":Over,"Line":line, "Under":Under})
print(df)
```

**OutPut**:

```
 Line  Over           Player Under
0   3.5  +114     Divock Origi  -149
1   1.5  -149      Dusan Tadic  +114
2     3  -114    Gabriel Jesus  -114
3   2.5  -167     Hakim Ziyech  +127
4   2.5  -114     Josip Ilicic  -114
5   2.5  +114      Mason Mount  -149
6   1.5  -108   Mbwana Samatta  -120
7   4.5  -137    Mohamed Salah  +106
8   2.5  +110       Papu Gomez  -143
9   1.5  +122     Paul Onuachu  -159
10  1.5  -149    Quincy Promes  +114
11  2.5  -114  Raheem Sterling  -114
12    4  +114  Roberto Firmino  -149
13  3.5  -149       Sadio Mané  +114
14  3.5  +117    Sergio Agüero  -152
15  3.5  -120    Tammy Abraham  -108
16  2.5  +127          Willian  -167
```

Comment: Ty so much for this response... I tried this code and received an error (NameError: name 'time' is not defined). I added the module "import time" and I received another error (selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: state element reference: element is not attached to the page document). I tried running the code multiple times and it work one time. Any suggestions @Kundruk? Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: I tried running it again and received a different message "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutExeption: Message:". After rerunning the script immediately after it worked perfectly.

Comment: It looks like the error is happening at different times. I have seen it happen on the Over/Under step. It also has happened after the program chooses UCL. It has also happened after the program selects ALL Available. I can send the errors for each if that would be helpful.

Comment: Do one thing possibly the script is running faster so use time.sleep(2) before each click event.

Comment: That seemed to work much more smoothly. However, I ran into an error (selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:) on the line using the variable "Playersname".

Comment: I uncommented the webdriverwait line containing "player" and it worked perfectly! Amazing work @Kunkuk!! I am so impressed. Thank you so much sir for your time and hard work. =) I will learn a lot from this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the full html-tree to see if your path is correct?

Edit: Looked it up myself.
Try this for the button

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('main div div div div div div div div ul li+li+li a ')
```

Comment: For debugging I would recommend to add more selectors step by step. To see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, ty @AnanasXpress. I will spend some more time over the next few days working on this.

Answer (score 1):

Please check carefully iframe is present on your page you need to switch to iframe before perform any action on a web element.

Please find link for switching more details :
https://chercher.tech/python/iframe-selenium-python

[image]

Comment: I will spend some time looking into this @Rock. Ty sir =)